# Removing a section of a variable

Tags: javascript

For one of my classes we were tasked with creating a simple javascript function that made use of the users time. I made a calculator that tells you when to wake up if you go to sleep right now, however I ran into a problem with the minutes of the outputs.

For the minutes, if they are less than 10 I add a 0 before, so that its 7:05 not 7:5. But since it adds the 0 to the minutes variable. It’s stuck that way for the rest of the times I use minutes

[image: What is happening]

So it applies the 0 for the 3:08, then stays with it for the rest of the uses.

Below is my javascript, I'm thinking that I need to just shorten the variable minutes to only be allowed to hold two characters but I'm not sure how to do that.

```
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours();
var minutes = time.getMinutes();
var amPM = "am";

if (hours > 12) {
  hours = hours - 12;
  amPM = "pm"
}

document.getElementById("currentTime").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;


function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
  return i;
}

function sleepFunction() {

  var time = new Date();
  var hours = time.getHours();
  var minutes = time.getMinutes();
  var amPM = "pm";
  var fixmin = "0";


  if (hours >= 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "pm"
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }

  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 52;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }
  if (hours >= 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "pm"
  }

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;
  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 15;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }
  if (hours >= 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "pm"
  }

  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;
  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 30;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "pm"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;
  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 30;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }

  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "am"
  }
  document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;
  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 30;


  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "am"
  }


  document.getElementById("demo4").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;
  var hours = hours + 1;
  var minutes = minutes + 30;

  if (minutes >= 60) {
    hours = hours + 1;
    minutes = minutes - 60;
  }
  if (minutes < 10) {
    minutes = fixmin + minutes;
  }
  if (hours > 12) {
    hours = hours - 12;
    amPM = "am"
  }

  document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + amPM;


  document.getElementById("averageWarning").innerHTML = "It Takes the Average Human 18 Minutes to Fall Aleep after viewing a screen";
  document.getElementById("sleepNow").innerHTML = "If you go to bed right now, you should set your alarm for one of these times";
}
```

Comment: Were you directed to write your own logic for handling time calculations? The builtin Date library in javascript can handle the addition of hours, minutes, etc, etc, and you can print the date in any format you wish.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be possible to use the built-in logic, because after the first calculation I'm just adding to the time, not pulling it anymore. My issue is just with the addition of the 0 to minutes, I think the other time calculations are working fine.

Comment: Perhaps instead of modifying the minutes variable, you can just add the zero when you're ready to display it, and not modify the underlying variable. `(minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes)`. This uses the ternary operator to test if minutes is under 10, then will output either the padding minutes, or minutes itself.

Comment: So would I just replace the minutes variable with (minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes) in the document,getElementbyid line?

Comment: Oh wow, it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes. You should understand the ternary operator before using it though. It's quite commonly used for displaying variables to a user, and it's a very useful operator to have knowledge of. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

Given that it's just a display issue, you could use your *checkTime* function any time you want to display the minutes.

For instance:

```
document.getElementById("demo5").innerHTML = hours + ':' + checkTime(minutes) + ' ' + amPM;
```

Fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/u3weyw6s/1/